# What makes it hard to develop vaccines for Syphilis and Gonorrhea?

Tags: bacteria, sex, sti, vaccine, std

Hope my question is more specific than [Why are some viruses harder to make vaccines for?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/16033/why-are-some-viruses-harder-to-make-vaccines-for)

Both Syphilis and Gonorrhea are caused by bacterial infection, rather than virus like HIV or COVID, which mutate relatively very frequently. What makes it technically difficult to develop vaccines for Syphilis and Gonorrhea?